# Color detection using camera

Tags: image-processing, camera

I have three images attached. The vertical Red strips in each image has different redness for different images. There are two strips in each image.

Looks very close, but there is difference and I like to detect redness difference in imaging.

Currently I extract these two red vertical strips in imaging and convert to HSV and look at H channel and S channel.

But the resolution of Redness is not acceptable.

What approach image processing or hardware use better camera model or any approach I use, would it be possible to get better data of redness detection for those vertical strips at images?

Image 1

[image]

Image 2

[image]

Image 3

[image]

Those images are captured by PointGray camera with 2M pixel resolution.

CM3-U3-13S2M-CS

Comment: What do the 3 images correspond to? How do you get colour images from a mono camera? Do you control the lighting in your setup and can you improve that? What about colour filtration whilst shooting?

Comment: Sorry I used color model. How to filter color while shooting, any sample code?

Comment: You screw a coloured glass filter onto the lens. I mean this... https://hoyafilterusa.com/how-filters-for-black-white-photography-work/

Comment: Thanks let me look into that.